# MYSQL: Filtrar registros en base a una columna

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

| solicitud | llamada | status | orden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1254 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 1254 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| 1254 | 2 | 6 | 3 |
| ***1254*** | ***6*** | ***7*** | ***4*** |
| 1246 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
| 1246 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| ***1246*** | ***3*** | ***8*** | ***3*** |
| 1253 | 1 | 9 | 1 |
| 1253 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| ***1253*** | ***7*** | ***4*** | ***3*** |
| 1321 | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| ***1321*** | ***8*** | ***4*** | ***2*** |

quiero filtrar los registros de cada solicitud en base al registro con orden más alto, quedaría algo así.

| request_num | number | status | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1254 | 6 | 7 | 4 |
| 1246 | 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 1253 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 1321 | 8 | 4 | 2 |

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: si, por supuesto.. con un group by y un max... lee sobre eso...

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste hasta el momento? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para MySql >= 8.0:**

Una opción es utilizar [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) con `DISTINCT`.

Para casa `solicitud` en cada columna obtenemos el primer valor ordenando por `orden DESC`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   solicitud,
   FIRST_VALUE(llamada) OVER (PARTITION BY solicitud ORDER BY orden DESC) AS llamada,
   FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY solicitud ORDER BY orden DESC) AS status,
   FIRST_VALUE(orden) OVER (PARTITION BY solicitud ORDER BY orden DESC) AS orden
FROM tabla;
```

**Otra opción (que funciona con versiones anteriores de MySql)** puede ser utilizar una subquery para filtrar (agrupando por `solicitud` y obteniendo el mayor valor de `orden`).

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE (solicitud, orden) IN (SELECT solicitud, MAX(orden)
                             FROM tabla
                             GROUP BY solicitud);
```

Estoy asumiendo que no hay valores de la columna `orden` repetidos por `solicitud`, sino la consulta te podría devolver mas de una fila por `solicitud`.

Answer (score 0):

select * from "tabla" where "columna" like "%palabra%" oder by solicitud desc, llamada desc, status desc orden;

Comment: eso solo la ordena, pero le sigue trayendo todos los registros....

Comment: el no especifica si quiere filtrar por algún dato, por lo que deduje que no encontró la palabra para decir ordenar.

Comment: si desearia filtrar seria como: select * from "tabla" where "columna" like "%palabra%" oder by solicitud desc, llamada desc, status desc orden;

Comment: claramente en su salida, dijo "quiero filtrar los registros"...